# how to fix "no free leases" issue in dhcp3?

Tags: linux, dhcp, ubuntu-10.04

I am facing **no free leases** issue. I am building a new server. I have successfully installed ltsp. Then, I configured the dhcp. This is my dhcpd.conf file.

```
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option broadcast-address 192.168.12.255;
option routers 192.168.12.205;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.12.205;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

next-server 192.168.12.205;

option root-path "192.168.12.205:/opt/ltsp/i386/";

subnet 192.168.12.0 netmask 255.255.255.0  {

range 192.168.12.55 192.168.12.100;

        host client1 {
                option root-path "192.168.12.205:/opt/ltsp/i386/";
                filename "/ltsp/i386/pxelinux.0";
                hardware ethernet 00:1d:72:04:8d:a9;
                fixed-address 192.168.12.69;
        }

}
```

Error is,

```
Dec 27 18:18:35 Dennis dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Dec 27 18:23:27 Dennis dhcpd: DHCPDISCOVER from 00:1d:72:04:8d:a9 via eth0: network 192.168.12/24: no free leases
```

I referred in internet and tried. But, I am not able to fix.

Can you guide me to fix this issue.

Comment: Not sure if it fixes all your problems, but there is a `;` missing in the `range 192.168...` line

Comment: @faker, I tried. it is not fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dhcpd probably needs write access to the leases file.

From http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/dhcpd.leases.5.html:

> When dhcpd is first installed, there is no lease database. However,
>   dhcpd requires that a lease database be present before it will start.
>   To make the initial lease database, just create an  empty  file 
>   called `/var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases`. You can do this with:

```
touch /var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases
```

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Well, I don't think you really need to create this file. Even if you remove this file, you just need to restart the dhcp server, and this file will be automatically created.

Comment: see above what the ubuntu documentation says.

Comment: @mgabriel , The dhcpd.leases file has been created automatically. There is no content in the file. But, Still it is giving same error.

Comment: try a chmod 0777 /var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases just to test if there is a problem with the write permissions.

Comment: @mgabriel , It is fixed. First, I deleted the /var/lib/dhcp3/dhcpd.leases file. Then, I created the new file with 0777 permission and changed the ownership to dhcpd. Now, It is okay.

Comment: With proper file ownership (such as user "dhcpd" on my system), you can back permissions off to 644, or maybe even less. No need for Execute permissions, as far as I can see.